# Flex & XML in IE-- Parse Me, Baby!

Tags: xml, apache-flex, internet-explorer

I've got a Flex 3 project. I'm having a problem with XML in Internet Explorer only. Pls see the problem lines below:

```
_clickURL = xhtml.a.@href.toString();
_mediaSource = xhtml.a.img.@src.toString();
```

These variables are coming up "" in IE. But, they grab the data in Safari and Firefox.

Any suggestions as to what the problem might be? Possible solution?

Thank you.

-Laxmidi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I've got it working now. The problem was case sensitivity.

This worked in Safari and Firefox:

```
_clickURL = xhtml.a.@href.toString();
_mediaSource = xhtml.a.img.@src.toString();
```

This worked in IE:

```
_clickURL = xhtml.A.@href.toString();
_mediaSource = xhtml.A.IMG.@src.toString();
```

IE capitalized the HTML tags in the XML.

-Laxmidi